# Twitter v2 api Stream Stop responding after some days

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, twitter, twitter-streaming-api

I am using the Twitter API v2 stream endpoint for listening to some specific events. Though I am facing an unusual problem. My stream stops responding after 2 to 3 days. it doesn't throw any error but i just don't get the data on any event.
Any one know what can be the problem.
i am using node 17.3.1 and node-twitter-api-v2 node client.

```
const streamFilter = await clientForStream.v2.getStream();

streamFilter.on(ETwitterStreamEvent.ConnectionError, (err) => console.log('Connection error!', err));
streamFilter.on(ETwitterStreamEvent.Connected, () => console.log('Stream is started.'));
```

Comment: have you tried disconnecting and reconnecting?

Comment: The question should be updated with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You should distill the code down to its barebone functionality. If it still doesn't work, include the snippet here to base the discussions on.

Comment: @AndyPiper yes i did have a mechanism to reconnect. it doesn't crash the server it just make stop listening to the tweets that i have defined in my rules. i have to manually restart my server to make it work.

Comment: What is the difference between reconnecting, and restarting your server - maybe something is getting cached that gets cleared when you restart?

Comment: Reconnecting is for stream, and restarting means rebooting the whole server. Maybe!

Comment: it was my javascript client issue, solved it by changing the client